# vCard sent with Twilio not properly rendered in iOS

Tags: twilio, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to send a vCard to my iOS using `curl`, but the vCard is not properly rendered in my iPhone.

```sh
EXCLAMATION_MARK='!'
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<acc>/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "Body=Test6$EXCLAMATION_MARK" \
--data-urlencode "MediaUrl=https://mighty-health-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vcf/James.vcf" \
--data-urlencode "From=+14155926669" \
--data-urlencode "To=+14159108243" \
-u <acc>:<token>
```

I tried different `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` with my file.

For Content-Disposition:

- `inline; filename="James.vcf"`
- `attachment; filename="James.vcf"`
- `inline; name="James"`
- `attachment; name="James"`

For Content-Type:

- `text/vcard`
- `text/x-vcard`
- `text/vcard`
- `text/vcard; charset=utf-8; name="fileName.vcf"`

The result is always the same:

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

I'd like to have ideas on what to try next or if you already experienced the same issue before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Troubleshooting problem

Turns out one of the configuration was correct, and the problem I was facing was a different one.

1. When Twilio receives a file for the first time, it caches
2. If you adjust the headers accordingly it won't impact the delivery of the VCF file, because it will use the cached version
3. There is a way to overcome that

## Twilio Caching

To remove the caching on your files or to set the appropriate cache policy, read: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024716314-How-Can-I-Change-the-Cache-Behavior-or-Message-Media-Files-

Troubleshooting I figured out that Twilio don't change cache based only on filename for VCF files, but by the file content itself, so you have to modify your file in order for it to clear the cache, not just the name.

## Correct configuration

In order to get the file properly parsed by an iOS phone, you can use the same file format as attached https://mighty-health-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/vcf/James+Li.vcf

#### Headers

The contact card on iOS can only display the same text as of your file, so name your file with the same `filename` header property on `Content-Type` and it should work accordingly

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="<You file name>.vcf"
Content-Type: text/x-vcard
Cache-Control: no-cache
```